# SFDX error for LiveChatTranscript object

Tags: community, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin

I have added LiveChatTranscript object in my unlocked package but while versioning getting error

**LiveChatTranscript: Invalid fullName, must end in a custom suffix ( for ex. __c )**

Can anyone help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the [LiveChat settings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/48/LiveChatDeployment/scratch-def/developer):

```
{
  "orgName": "Sample Org",
  "edition": "developer",
  "settings": {
    "liveAgentSettings": {
      "enableLiveAgent": true
    }
  }
}
```

You need a definitionFile specified in your `packageDirectories` section of sfdx-project.json:

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "package": "my-package-name",
      "versionName": "ver 0.1",
      "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT",
      "default": true,
      "definitionFile": "config/scratch-features.json"
    }
  ],
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "48.0"
}
```

The file name is relative to sfdx-project.json, so in this case, a file named `config/scratch-features.json`, or whatever you decide to call it. You'll need to include any other dependent features in this file as well. The link above allows you to explore the various settings and how you reference them in [Scratch Org Definition Files](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file.htm).

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, Can you pls help on https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/303550/sfdx-error-for-external-objects